# No me trae los datos para editar en vista

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

Veran, estoy usando laravel 8 con livewire y en mi vista editar no trae los datos ya existentes a editar. Me gustaria que me ayudasen a entender cual seria el error que estoy cometiendo o si me hace falta algo. A continuacion compartire la parte del codigo que menciono e intentando compartir todo lo posible para que entiendan.

Vista editar livewire:

````
```<div>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-simple">
        <div class="modal-content p-3 p-md-5">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                <div class="text-center mb-4">
                    <h3 class="mb-2">{{__('Update user')}}</h3>
                    <p class="text-muted">{{__('Update user information')}}</p>
                </div>
                <form class="row g-3 d-flex align-items-center" wire:submit.prevent="update" id="userUpdate">
                    @csrf
                    <!-- PHOTO -->
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <label class="form-label" for="photo">{{__('Photo')}}</label>
                        <div class="image-upload">
                            <div class="thumb text-center">
                                <div class="avatar-preview">
                                    <div class="profilePicPreview" @if($photo_edit) style="background: url('{{$photo_edit->temporaryUrl()}}')" @else @if($profile_photo !=null) style="background: url('{{asset('uploads/profile/'.$profile_photo)}}')" @endif @endif>
                                        <button type="button" class="remove-image"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="avatar-edit">
                                    <input type="file" class="profilePicUpload" wire:model="photo_edit" id="image_edit" name="" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
                                    <label for="image_edit" class="bg--primary">{{__('Add photo')}}</label>
                                </div>
                                <small class="mt-2 text-center">{{__('Compatibilities')}}: <b>jpeg, jpg, png</b> {{__('Resized to')}}: <b>{{$image_width}}x{{$image_height}}</b>px.</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        @error('photo_edit')
                        <div class="badge bg-label-danger mt-2 w-100">{{ __($message) }}</div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <!-- Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="first_name">Name:</label>
                        <input wire:model="editedFirstName" type="text" class="form-control" id="first_name">
                        @error('editedFirstName')
                        <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <!-- Last Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="last_name">Last Name:</label>
                        <input wire:model="editedLastName" type="text" class="form-control" id="last_name">
                        @error('editedLastName')
                        <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                    <!-- Middle Name -->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="middle_name">Middle Name:</label>
                        <input wire:model="editedMiddleName" type="text" class="form-control" id="middle_name">
                        @error('editedMiddleName')
                        <span class="error">{{ $message }}</span>
                        @enderror
</div>```
````

No comparto todo porque seria mucho codigo, pero mas o menos asi seria la estructura de la vista que tengo. Ahora el componente livewire:

````
```<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire\Patients;

use App\Models\City;
use App\Models\Patient;
use App\Models\Program;
use App\Models\State;
use App\Models\User;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithPagination;
use Image;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class Edit extends Component
{
    use WithPagination;

    public $ssn;
    public $phone;
    public $email;
    public $address;
    public $unit_apt;
    public $city_id;
    public $state_id;
    public $zip_code;
    public $employeent;
    public $patient;
    public $programs_id;

    public $editedFirstName;
    public $editedLastName;
    public $editedMiddleName;

    public $photo_edit;
    public $profile_photo;
    public $user;
    public $type_person;

    //Image
    public $image_width = 240;
    public $image_height = 240;

    public $cities;
    public $states;
    public $programs;

    public $dob;
    public $employee;
    public $password;
    public $profile;

    protected $listeners = [
        'PatientsShowChange',
        'PatientsShowRender' => 'render'
    ];
    public function mount()
    {
        // Carga los datos iniciales en la propiedad $employees
        $this->employee = Patient::all();
        $this->cities = City::all();
        $this->states = State::all();
        $this->programs = Program::all();
    }
    //Edit
    protected function rules()
    {
        $rules = [
            'user.email' => 'required|string|email',
            // Definir reglas comunes para todos los usuarios aquí
        ];

        // Reglas específicas para patient
        $rules['profile.first_name'] = 'nullable|string';
        $rules['profile.last_name'] = 'nullable|string';
        $rules['profile.middle_name'] = 'nullable|string';
        $rules['user.phone'] = 'nullable|string';
        $rules['patient.address'] = 'nullable|string';
        $rules['patient.city_id'] = 'nullable|exists:cities,id';
        $rules['patient.state_id'] = 'nullable|exists:states,id';
        $rules['programs_id'] = 'nullable|exists:programs,id';

        return $rules;
    }

    public function edit(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->profile = $user->profile;

            $this->phone = $this->user->phone;
            $this->email = $this->user->email;
            $this->editedFirstName = $this->user->profile->first_name;
            $this->editedLastName = $this->user->profile->last_name;
            $this->editedMiddleName = $this->user->profile->middle_name;
            $this->profile_photo = $this->user->profile->photo;

            if ($user->patient) {
                $this->address = $this->patient->address;
                $this->city_id = $this->patient->city_id;
                $this->state_id = $this->patient->state_id;
                $this->programs_id = $this->patient->programs_id;
            
        }
    }

    public function update()
    {
        $this->validate();
        if ($this->password) {
            $this->user->password = bcrypt($this->password);
        }
        if ($this->photo_edit) {
            // Eliminar la foto anterior si existe
            if ($this->profile->photo) {
                // Elimina la foto anterior almacenada en el servidor
                File::delete(public_path('uploads/profile/' . $this->profile->photo));
            }

            // Guarda la nueva foto
            $photo = Str::slug($this->profile->name) . '-' . Carbon::now()->locale('co')->format('Y-m-d-H-i-s') . '.' . $this->photo_edit->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Image::make($this->photo_edit)->resize($this->image_width, $this->image_height)->save(public_path('uploads/profile/' . $photo, 50));
            $this->profile->photo = $photo;
        }

        //$this->user->profile->first_name = $this->first_name;

        if ($this->user) {
            $this->user->phone = $this->phone;
            $this->user->email = $this->email;
            $this->user->profile->photo = $this->profile_photo;

            $this->user->save();
        }

        if ($this->profile) {
            $this->profile->first_name = $this->editedFirstName;
            $this->profile->last_name = $this->editedLastName;
            $this->profile->middle_name = $this->editedMiddleName;

            $this->profile->save();
        }

        if ($this->patient) {
            $this->patient->address = $this->address;
            $this->patient->city_id = $this->city_id;
            $this->patient->state_id = $this->state_id;
            $this->patient->programs_id = $this->programs_id;

            $this->patient->save();
        }

        $this->emit('alert', __('Registered User!'));
        return redirect()->route('users.index');
        //$this->emitTo('users.show', 'render');
        //$this->emit('alert', __('Updated User!'), '#edit');
        //$this->emit('UsersShowRender');
    }
    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.patients.edit');
    }
}```
````

Ahora la ruta de la vista donde se llama la vista livewire:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('title', __('Employee'))
@section('content')
<div class="container-xxl flex-grow-1 container-p-y">
    <livewire:patients.edit :editId="$patient->id" />
</div>
@endsection
```

El controlador y la ruta:

Controlador:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PatientsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('patients.index');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        $patient = User::findOrFail($id);
        
        return view('patients.edit', compact('patient'));
    }
}
```

Y la ruta:

```
//patients
        Route::group(['prefix'=>'patients'],function (){
        Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\PatientsController::class, 'index'])->name('patients.index');
        Route::get('/edit/{patient_id}', [\App\Http\Controllers\PatientsController::class, 'edit'])->name('patients.edit');
        //employees
        });
```